# How to add style from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, hyperlink

I want to add a style `A:Hover` to a HyperLink control from code behind.

I can do like this :

```
HyperLink hlRow = new HyperLink();
hlRow.Style.Add("color", "#000000");
hlRow.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");
```

But how can I add styles for `A:Hover` for the hyperlink control?
Do I need to define a class and associate that class with this control, if yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:hover` is a selector, and not a style. What you're doing in your example is adding inline styles to an element, and a selector equivalent for that obviously doesn't make much sense.

You can add a class to your link: `hlRow.CssClass = 'abc';`
And define your class as such:

```
a.abc:hover {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hover is a pseudo-class, not a selector; this is a selector: `ul li a { ... }`

Comment: well yes, *part of a* selector is what i meant to convey: still in the sense that trying to add it to an element doesn't make sense, as it's rather used to *find* matching elements. but yeah, thanks for the remark

Comment: Hey guys, i have a follow up questions, what if i have a menu Item in the aspx code, that i want to assign to him the CSS class.
how can i reach this property which is a webcontrol property and missing from the MenuItem Control?  im trying to do a simple thing which is to create style for "Selected" mode...so the user will know which page is the current active page. any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 25):

You can use the CssClass property of the hyperlink:

```
LiteralControl ltr = new LiteralControl();
        ltr.Text = "<style type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">" +
                    @".d
                    {
                        background-color:Red;
                    }
                    .d:hover
                    {
                        background-color:Yellow;
                    }
                    </style>
                    ";
        this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(ltr);
        this.HyperLink1.CssClass = "d";
```

Comment: Thanks. BTW, I do have the aspx page, I can directly write the CSS class over there instead of using LiteralControl! :-)

Comment: I'd love to upvote you but for some crazy reason my vote limit is reached for "today" (which is not my today, but the US today) so I can't. So instead I'll leave this comment. And maybe when my ban on voting is lifted I can remember this post and come back and vote it :)

Comment: Wonderful trick. To make it more dynamic, put this under a method and replace class name with a token and user String.Format to dynamically populate it.

Answer (score 16):

Use

```
HyperLink hlRow = new HyperLink();
hlRow.Attributes.Add("Style", "color:#000000");
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

**Html Markup**

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

**Code**

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Style style = new Style();
    style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    this.Page.Header.StyleSheet.CreateStyleRule(style, this, "#" + HyperLink1.ClientID + ":hover");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure the aspx page has `AutoEventWireup="true"` and not  `AutoEventWireup="false"`

Answer (score 1):

If no file available for download, I needed to disable the asp:linkButton, change it to grey and eliminate the underline on the hover.  This worked:

```
.disabled {
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```
LinkButton button = item.FindControl("lnkFileDownload") as LinkButton;
button.Enabled = false;
button.CssClass = "disabled";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

So just don't apply styles directly like that, and apply a class "foo", and then define that in your CSS specification:

```
a.foo { color : orange; }
a.foo:hover { font-weight : bold; }
```

Answer (score -2):

**try this**

```
 lblMsg.Text = @"Your search result for <b style=""color:green;"">" + txtCode.Text.Trim() + "</b> ";
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with hover.